# VBA class module: get property from an object using another property

Tags: excel, vba, class, object

All,
I am setting-up a class module structure in VBA to add plans that have multiple milestones, but I'm quite new to it. I did the following:

- A class module called 'Plan' that contains a 'name' property (string) and a 'Milestones' property (class Milestones).
- This milestones class module is a collection of objects of a class module called 'Milestone'.
- The 'Milestone' class has a 'name' property and a 'value' property.

So in my module I am now specifying the milestones for a specific plan:

```
Plan.Milestones.Add "MilestoneA", Cells(i, 5)
Plan.Milestones.Add "MilestoneB", Cells(i, 7)
...
```

Until now everything is fine. Now for MilestoneC I would like to know the value of MilestoneA. How do I get the value for the Milestone with name 'MilestoneA'.

I know the below code would give me the answer, but I don't want to hardcode 'item(1)' (I want to use the name):

```
Plan.Milestones.Item(1).Value
```

In the clsMilestones class:

```
Private prvt_Milestones As New Collection

Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As clsMilestone
    Set Item = prvt_Milestones(Index)
End Property

Sub Add(param_Name As String, param_Value As String)

    Dim new_milestone As clsMilestone
    Set new_milestone = New clsMilestone

    new_milestone.Name = param_Name
    new_milestone.Value = param_Value

    prvt_Milestones.Add new_milestone
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `dictionary` of `Milestone` classes in the `plan class` and set the `key` to be the "Milestone_x" and the `item` to be a `milestone class`

Then you can say `Plan.Milestones("Milestone99")`

Answer (score 7):

Your `Milestones` class is a *collection class*. By convention, collection classes have an `Item` property that is the class' *default member*. You can't easily specify a class' default member in VBA, but it's not impossible.

Export the code file, open it in Notepad. Locate your `Public Property Get Item` member and add a `VB_UserMemId` attribute - while you're there you can add a `VB_Description` attribute, too:

```
Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As Variant) As Milestone
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
Attribute Item.VB_Description = "Gets the item at the specified index, or with the specified name."
    Set Item = prvt_Milestones(Index)
End Property
```

The `UserMemId = 0` is what makes the property the class' *default member* - note that only one member in the class can have that value.

Don't save and close just yet.

You'll want to make your collection class work with a `For Each` loop too, and for that to work you'll need a `NewEnum` property that returns an `IUnknown`, with a number of attributes and flags:

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_Description = "Gets an enumerator that iterates through the collection."
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"    
    Set NewEnum = prvt_Milestones.[_NewEnum]
End Property
```

Note that your internal encapsulated `Collection` has a hidden member with a name that begins with an underscore - that's illegal in VBA, so to invoke it you need to surround it with square brackets.

Now this code is legal:

```
Dim ms As Milestone
For Each ms In Plan.Milestones
    Debug.Print ms.Name, ms.Value ', ms.DateDue, ...
Next
```

Save the file, close it, and re-import it into your project.

Since you're populating the collection using a string key (at least that's what your `Add` method seems to be doing), then the client code can use either the index or the key to retrieve an item.

And now that `Item` is the class' *default member*, this is now legal:

```
Set milestoneA = Plan.Milestones("Milestone A").Value
```

Note that your `Add` method needs to specify a value for the `Key` argument when adding to the internal collection - if you want the items keyed by `Name`, use the `Name` as a key:

```
Public Sub Add(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Value As Variant)
    Dim new_milestone As Milestone
    Set new_milestone = New Milestone

    new_milestone.Name = Name
    new_milestone.Value = Value

    prvt_Milestones.Add new_milestone, Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that I dropped the `cls` prefix on the class name. I've never seen any class in any object model with a `cls` prefix, for one, and it reeks of *Systems Hungarian* notation, [which was nothing more than an unfortunate misunderstanding](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) and should never have come to be.

Comment: +1 Very nicely done. I would sure be interested (as I'm sure a lot of people would) in a little more detail on the NewEnum property you added.

Comment: Ok I just tested it and it's beautiful. Thanks Mat's Mug

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to the Milestones class that returns the milestone based on the name:

```
Property Get SelectByName(strMilestoneName as string) as clsMilestone
     Dim vIndex
     'Add code here to find the index of the milestone in question
     vIndex = ????????

     Set SelectByName = prvt_Milestones(Index)
End Property
```

OR

Edit the Item Property to Allow selection by either Index or Name:

```
Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As clsMilestone
    If isNumeric(Index) then
       Set Item = prvt_Milestones(Index)
    Else
       'Find Item based on Name
        Dim vIndex
        vIndex = ?????
       Set Item = prvt_Milestones(vIndex)
     End If
End Property
```

Comment: I suppose this would mean I still need to loop through all milestones to find the corresponding item, right?

Comment: @Hans if you're **specifying a key when you add the items** to the collection, you don't need to iterate anything or to use a dictionary. But **you're not showing us** your `Add` method, so we all have to make assumptions.